# custom validation using Javax or Hibernate validation for collections

Tags: java, spring, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I am using **validation-api-1.1.0.Final** and **hibernate-validator-5.3.6.Final**. I would like to do validation for the below case,

Information received from the client,

```
"BookInfo":[  
            {  
               "key":"book.name",
               "value":"D12345678"
            },
            {  
               "key":"author.phoneNumber",
               "value":{  
                  "phone_number":"0123456789",
                  "numberInfo":{  
                     "contryCode":"44",
                     "numberRegion":"GB",
                     "numberType":"MOBILE"
                  }
               }
            },
            {  
               "key":"author.email",
               "value":"a@b.com"
            }
         ]
```

Validation rules are specified in the database like below,

```
 "BookInfo":[  
                     {  
                        "key":"name",
                        "type": "text"
                        "Validation":{  
                           "pattern":"[a-z,A-Z]"
                        }
                     },
                     {  
                        "key":"author.phoneNumber",
                        "type": "tel" //It should perform custom validation i have written for phone number validation
                        "localValidation":{  
                        }
                     },
                     {  
                        "key":"author.email",
                        "type":"email",
                        "localValidation":{
                        "pattern": "[*@gmail.com]" //It should perform javax email validation+pattern mentioned here
                        },
                        "optional":false
                     }
                  ]
```

I would like to perform a validation based on the rule stored in the DB with the payload we have received from the client. I would like to use above 2-library to perform these validations. I am storing the above 2-information in a JAVA bean like below

**BookClient.java**

```
public Class BookClient {
  private List<Map<String, Object>> bookInfo;
}
```

**BookFromDB.java**

```
public Class BookFromDB {
  private List<Map<String, Object>> bookInfo;
}
```

I have browsed enough and I couldn't get any thread which will perform validation for List It would be great if I get any hint or any other alternative way to perform this validation efficiently.

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Validator doesn't support validation of free form objects for now.

It's something we (mostly Marko Bekhta) are working on for 6.1, especially to be able to validate JSON objects.

Don't hold your breath though, we don't have any estimated date for the release.

Comment: so no other way now? we don't have either option in javax-validation API?